# How to set process to the lowest possible priority on Linux?

Tags: linux, nice, ionice

I want to set the process to the lowest possible scheduling on Linux. I came up with the following:

```
nice -n 39 ionice -c 3 chrt -i 0 command
```

Are there also other settings that one can set for a process to "lower" the process priority? Are these settings the "lowest" possible?

More often than not, I do `make -j$(nproc)` or `cmake` or heavy tar processes that take full available I/O, memory and CPU on my machine. What is really frustrating, is that my mouse starts lagging. So I want to prevent it.

Comment: One word, because I'm on phone and can't write an answer: cgroups2

Comment: from `man nice`: Niceness values range from -20 (most favorable to the process) to 19 (least favorable to the process). So replace 20 with 19.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do not think I can affect cgroups2 as a normal user. Is there a way to set cpu_shares of a single command as a normal user?

Comment: @sudodus you are right, but it should be +39, in case we start from -20. But I think niceness is getting ignored because chrt sets the process to SCHED_IDLE. Would be nice to get confirmation on that - thus the quesiton.

Comment: @KamilCuk you should indeed be able to slice off new cgroups from your user slice, as unprivileged user. But the devil's in the details, usually...

Comment: Well , technically , Setting to the lowest Possible Priority is to terminate the Process , thereby ensuring that it is never even Scheduled to Execute ! [[ Every Other Process will have higher Priority to get Scheduled & then get Executed ! ]]

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 ``man sched`` contains ``SCHED_IDLE can be used only at static priority 0; the process nice value has no influence for this policy.``. I.e. since ``chrt -i 0`` is used to set a scheduling policy of ``SCHED_IDLE`` don't think the initial ``nice -n 39`` to set the nice value is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the results (except for the I/O scheduling) of whatever you do with:

```
/bin/ps -eo pid,rtprio,class,pri,ni,args
```

As a regular user you get access to Systemd limits (or at least some of them) with

```
systemd-run --user --nice=18 sleep 1234 # see --property=
```

Comment: The problem with `systemd-run` like with `-Pt` is that it does not correctly preserve the exit status when receiving a signal. Except for that it is a great tool for that.

Comment: In systemd 219 on a server if I execute that `systemd-run` from root I get `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory`.